# Docker сбрость контейнер до первоначального состояния

Tags: docker

Имею следующую структуру для быстрой сборки wordpress проекта.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 version: '4'
    
    services: 
      # Database
      db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
          - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
          MYSQL_USER: wordpress
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
        networks:
          - wpsite
      #phpmyadmin
      phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports: 
          - '8080:80'
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: db
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        networks:
          - wpsite
      # Wordpress  
      wordpress:
        build: 
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile_wp
        depends_on: 
          - db
        ports:
          - '8000:80'
        restart: always
        volumes: ['./src:/var/www/html']
        environment:
          WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
          WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
        networks:
          - wpsite
    networks:
      wpsite:
    volumes:
      db_data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM wordpress:latest
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host=192.168.1.41" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Подскажите, правильно ли я понял, что docker контейнеры собираются с docker образа только при первом скачивании его с Docker Hub? Я имею ввиду, что если я, скажем, перезагружу компьютер или остановлю контейнер через `docker stop id`, то при повторном запуске контейнера `docker-composer up -d` его локальное состояние не сбросится то первоначального (как в репозиториях гитхаба). А останется таким, каким я его "сделал" на компьютере.

Если это так, то как мне сделать полный "откат" к начальному состоянию контейнера. У меня, к примеру, сломался вордпресс и я хочу восстановить его, чтобы он был как при первом скачивании образа через `docker-composer up`.

Выход что я нашел это удалению всех локальных образом и контейнеров с машины, но мне кажется что есть способ лучше, но у меня не получилось его найти.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "состоянием контейнера"? Образы контейнеров так-то принципиально неизменяемые (а если вы их меняете на лету, то вы делаете что-то сильно не так)

Comment: @andreymal Я имею ввиду побайтовое их состояние. Скажем, чтобы все файлы были такие же, как при первом скачивании

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите, правильно ли я понял, что docker контейнеры собираются с docker образа только при первом скачивании его с Docker Hub?

Контейнер - это экземпляр образа. Образ может иметь сколько угодно контейнеров различной конфигурации. Если здесь подразумевается команда `run`, то скачивание осуществится только при ее первом выполнении, далее этот образ будет на вашем компьютере. Команда `run` как раз создает новый контейнер.

> при повторном запуске контейнера `docker-composer up -d`

Это не повторный запуск, а сборка, создание нового контейнера и его запуск. Существующий контейнер запускается командой [start](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/start/) (вместо [up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)).

> скажем, перезагружу компьютер или остановлю контейнер через docker stop id, то при повторном запуске ... его локальное состояние не сбросится то первоначального

Конечно не сбросится, даже если вы запустите на другой машине, это будет все то же приложение, в этом и смысл контейнеризации.

> как мне сделать полный "откат" к начальному состоянию

Приложение в контейнере не может быть изменено, т.к. контейнер является изолятором для него. Измениться может файловая система контейнера, в которой находится это приложение, если оно с ней работает. "Полный откат" - это образ.